# laravel pivot returning null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a site which using laravel framework. I have two tables with many to many relationship, the table are `training` and `budget`, and also a join table `budget_training`.

in both training and budget model, i define the relation like this;

```
// in Training model
public function budget(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->withPivot('amount');
} 

// in Budget model
public function training(){
   return $this->belongsToMany('Training')->withPivot('amount');
}
```

why in the view `$training->pivot` is returning null? what is wrong with the code?

full code

```
// Budget.php
class Budget extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    // public function training(){
    //  return $this->belongsToMany('Training')->withPivot('amount');
    // }

}

// Training.php
class Training extends \Eloquent {

    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        // 'title' => 'required'
    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'city',
        'province',
        'budget_year',
        's_date',
        'e_date'
    ];

    public function material(){
        return $this->hasMany('Material');
    }

    public function budget(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Budget')->withPivot('amount');
    }

}
```

code to insert the data

```
public function postStore(){
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Training::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $training = Training::create($data);

    foreach(Input::get('budgets') as $k=>$v){
        preg_match('/(\d)/', $k, $budget_id);
        if(count($budget_id) > 0){
            $budget_training = new BudgetTraining;
            $budget_training->budget_id = $budget_id[0];
            $budget_training->training_id = $training->id;
            $budget_training->amount = str_replace(',', '', $v);
            $budget_training->save();
        }
    }

    return Redirect::to('trainings/index');
}
```

index.blade.php containing this, `$trainings` from its controller

```
@foreach($trainings as $training)
            {{ var_dump($training->pivot) }}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $training->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $training->budget_year }}</td>
                <td>{{ $training->city }}, {{ $training->province }}</td>
                <td>{{ $training->s_date }}</td>
                <td>{{ $training->e_date }}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ url('trainings/edit/'.$training->id) }}" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                    <a href="{{ url('trainings/destroy/'.$training->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
```

here is the index method.

```
public function getIndex(){
    $trainings = Training::all();

    return View::make('trainings.index', compact('trainings'));
}
```

Comment: The relationships seem to be fine. can you show the full code how you load the model etc?

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get the `$training` variable in `$training->pivot`. I want to see that part of your code

Comment: @lukasgeiter : ok, updated.

Comment: And is `$trainings` the result of something like `$budget->training` ?

Comment: you mean `$budget->training` returning NULL as well? if so, yes `$budget->training` is returning NULL

Comment: Well to be able to access the pivot object of a model the model has to be loaded by a relationship. I'm not sure if you are doing that part right so please update the question again with the controller code that injects `$trainings` into the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the pivot object of your models because they haven't been joined over the pivot table.

In your code you just select all the training rows from the db without any use of the pivot table. So you have no connection to `Budget` and therefore no pivot object.

What would work instead would be getting all trainings from one budget like that

```
$trainings = Budget::find(1)->training;

foreach($trainings as $training){
    var_dump($training->pivot);
}
```

Or what you probably want is this:

```
foreach($trainings as $training){
    $budgets = $training->budget;
    foreach($budgets as $budget){
        var_dump($budget->pivot);
    }
}
```

If you do this make sure you use

```
$trainings = Training::with('budget')->get();
```

So it doesn't have to query the db every time you call `->budget` on a training

Comment: yeah! i am a dumb :D, can't find this on official laravel doc. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access pivot data, you can do it this way, for example:

```
$training = Training->with('budget')->find(1);
echo $training->name;
foreach ($training->budget as $b) {
  echo $b->name.' '.$b->pivot->amount."<br />"
}
```

So you don't access pivot data on model, but on relation, in this case not:

```
$training->pivot->amount
```

but

```
$training->budget[$i]->pivot->amount
```

(assuming `$i` is loop index)